# Logistic Regression -- Question about inverse of a features probability

Tags: regression, logistic

I'm working on a customer churn model. Currently i have a variable for increased returns (1/0). After i run the model and convert the coefficient to and odds ratio, then convert that to probability; I wind up with 70%. (Churn =1, Not Churn = 0)

My question is can i use the inverse of this probability to say that a customer with decreased or flat returns has a 30% probability to "not churn". If i actually flip this relationship in the data and feed it to the model, it starts to generate a lot more false positives, and accuracy falls drastically.

Any help would be extremely appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If
$$P(churn = 1 \mid increasedReturns = 1) = 0.70$$
then
$$P(churn = 0 \mid increasedReturns = 1) = 0.30$$

70% is the probability of churn *given* that the customer has increased returns.

So, 30% is the probability of "no churn" given that the customer has increased returns.

To find the probability of a churn for a customer with decreased of flat return, you need calculate the probability of churn when increasedReturn = 0.
$$P(churn = 1 \mid increasedReturns = 0)$$

Comment: Ok. That makes sense. Thank you so much for the answer!